# Fixed menu but body is covering the menu

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a fixed menu like on this site: http://www.thethingswemake.co.uk/web_carsonified.htm

The menu is fixed like I want it too but the main wrapper is going ontop instead of below the menu: this is what I have http://jsfiddle.net/qacaT/

HTML:

```
<div id="topWrapper">
    <div id="topContainer">
         <a href="index.html">
        <header id="top_header">
            <h1>MacroPlay Games</h1>
        </header>
    </a>

    <nav id="topnav">
        <ul>
            <a href="index.html"><li>Home</li></a>
            <a href="about.html"><li>About</li></a>
            <a href="video.html"><li>Trailers</li></a>
            <button type="button" data-state="0" style="float:right">Cinema Mode</button>
        </ul>
    </nav>   

        <div id="logoTop"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="body_div">
        <div id="dimPlayer" class="dim"></div>
        <div id="video_container">
            <video id="trailers" poster="poster.jpg">
                <source src="vLast.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="vLast.webm" type="video/webm">
            </video>
            <nav>
               <div id="controls" class="cAnimated cFadeInRight">
                    <div id="defaultBar">
                        <div id="progressBar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <button id="playButton">Play</button>
                    <button id="vol" onclick="showSlider()">Vol</button>      
                    <button id="containSlider"> 
                                <input type="range" id="vSlider" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.5"/></button>
                    <div id='containTime'><span id='timeDisplay'>0:00</span><span>/</span><span id='duration'>0:00</span></div>
                    <button id="full">Full</button>
                    <button id="mute">Mute</button>

               </div> 
               <div id="playlist" class="animated fadeInRight">
                    <div class="thumb" id="tb1"><img src="TbGow.jpg" onClick="changeTrailer('vGow')"/></div>
                    <div class="thumb" id="tb2"><img src="TbLast.jpg" onClick="changeTrailer('vLast')"/></div>
                    <div class="thumb" id="tb3"><img src="TbTwo.jpg" onClick="changeTrailer('vTwo')"/></div>
               </div>
            </nav>
        </div>



    <aside id="sidebar">
    <div id="side_events">
        <h1>News</h1>
        <ul id="events">
            <li>Half-Life 3 Release: <time>04/01/13</time></li>
            <li>Borderlands 3 Release: <time>05/29/13</time></li>
            <li>E3 2013 Starting: <time>08/11/13</time></li>
            <li>Playstation 4 Release: <time>08/31/13</time></li>
            <li>Xbox 720 Release: <time>09/01/13</time></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

        <div id="side_trailer">
            <a href="video.html"><img src="TbGow.jpg" /></a>
        </div>

    <div id="side_advert">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/W65o9R2.jpg" alt="Blackberry's Z10" title="Blackberry's Z10" id="advert">
    </div>                     
</aside>

</div>

<footer id="footer">
    &copy; Copyright  by SimKessy
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
#topWrapper {
    /*border:1px solid #00ffff;*/
    background-color:#0d0d0d;
    text-align:center;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
}
#topContainer {
    /*border:1px solid #00ff00;*/
    height:56px;
    width:784px;
    margin:0px auto;
    text-align:left;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#wrapper{
    max-width: 850px;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-box; /*means this is a box with children inside*/
    -moz-box-orient:vertical;
    -moz-box-flex:1;
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1; /*allows site to grow or shrink 1 = flex 0 = statix*/
    background-color: #B137D6;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: static;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add 'z-index' css property to the menu. Menu has to have bigger z-index than wrapper in order to stay on top. example:

```
#menu {
z-index:2;
}

#wrapper {
z-index:1;
}
```

by default all elements have `z-index:0;` so if you only add `z-index:1;` to the menu you're safe.

after adding z-index you need to give top margin to #body div like this:

```
#body_div{
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-box-orient:horizontal;
    color:#000000;
    margin-top:200px;

}
```

see updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qacaT/1/

Comment: Won't that leave the content in the same position but hide it? Therefore permanently hide those items.

Comment: Hey, sorry I took so long. I don't know why but nothing has changed when I try to copy the CSS into Aptana. It stays the same.

Comment: But yea this is what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: did you copy the code from the right jsfiddle? the only changes you need to do are add z-index:9; to #topWrapper and  margin-top:200px; to #body_div ... if this still doesn't work ... try clearing your browser cache and refresh the page.

Comment: Yes that's what I have. I posted what I have in http://jsfiddle.net/N4s47/  and it works. Whenever I launch from Aptana it looks like it used to. Ran CCleaner so cache was wiped. This weird.

Comment: This is what it looks like online: http://www3.carleton.ca/clubs/sissa/html5/videoFixed.html  Might be an issue with flexbox

Comment: If there's no change, you must have some conflict with another script/plugin. This is something you will have to troubleshoot to find out why it's happening so you can then solve it.

Comment: Turns out I was linking to the wrong CSS file all along (very stupid) sorry.

Comment: there's a problem with your solution. You'll notice that in the body all the elements other than the video container can't be accessed (the sidebar basically)

Answer (score -1):

Please use z-index property

```
#topWrapper {
/*border:1px solid #00ffff;*/
background-color:#0d0d0d;
text-align:center;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
z-index:9999; /*like this*/
}
```

Comment: that didn't work unfortunately. I think z-index deals with what element is displayed if they are in the same position right? The content wrapper is hitting the top off the window. So if I change index the menu may go to the front but I still won't be able to see the body content because it will be covered by the menu. Am I wrong?

Comment: YOu will have to set the positions  as well . I am creating a jsfiddle for you .